# GAM with composite functions (mgcv)

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm currently doing OLS regressions on the model below

y(M, F) = b0 + b1*M + b2*M^2 + b3*D*M^3 + b4*ln(F) + b5*M*ln(F) (D=0 if M<0, D=1 otherwise)

where M=ln(K/F)=ln(K)-ln(F) so M is actually a composite function of ln(F) with K and F being independent variables

To give some context, we are in the field of derivatives in financial engineering.

y is the implied volatility, K is the strike and F is the value of the underlying in an option derivative contract.

K and F are always positive and K is generally 0.5*F < K < 2*F.

y is always positive, approximately lognormally distributed.

I've started to explore GAMs with mgcv, at first with simple models on K, M, F in separation with both K and F showing non-linear behaviour.

Then I've moved on to the main-effects + interactions structure e.g. f_1(x) + f_2(z) + f_3(x,z) as the "OLS model" above suggests.

Reading through the docs I've come to the conclucsion that

Model 1 with tensors "ti"

```
model1 <- gam(y~ ti(K) + ti(F) + ti(K, F), data=df_in)
```

is the preferred way to define this interaction models albeit a form like the below is perfectly fine too

```
model2 <- gam(y~ s(K) + s(F) + te(K, F), data=df_in)
```

As you can see I'm using K and F as independent variables instead of M and F.

My question is using the (M, F) pair would still make sense and how should I do it?

In other words a model like

```
model3 <- gam(y~ ti(M) + ti(F) + ti(M, F), data=df_in)
```

would make sense as M depends on F?

M has the advantage of "normalizing" data across instruments as F might be 10, 100, 1000 and so on so it'd much better to use M instead of K (as the "OLS model does).